# How to create a single line of text with hyperlink or other elements on same line in R Shiny?

Tags: r, hyperlink, shiny

In R Shiny dashboard, I am trying to write lines of text with hyperlinks at the end of sentences or in-between words using a ",". However, the second tag, in this case a hyperlink goes to second line.  How do I keep all tags on the same line?

I have tried the code below and several variations:

```
fluidRow(h4("We recently launched a new initiative.  For more information visit:")),h4(a("Search for it", href="www.google.com"))
```

We recently launched a new initiative. Fore more information: Search for it (with a hyperlink to Google as a placeholder).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need a comma. If you want your link also formatted with the `h4` style, the code would look like this:

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      h4("We recently launced a new initiative. For more information visit: ", a("Search for it", href = "wwww.google.com"))
    )
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  }
)
```

Which results in:

[image]

Comment: I think I was missing a parentheses. Thanks!